# Jackson ObjectMapper is null in JUnit 5 Controller Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, junit5

I have tried with @Autowired on the objectMapper, also tried to Mock it but no success, I just want to use the writeValueAsStringMethod so I do not have to pass a long json string to the content method below.

If I mark my class with `@SpringBootTest` and also `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` it works (the objectmapper is not null) but I believe that there must be another way so that it does not become mandatory to use this annotations.

TestClass:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CarControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private CarController carController;

    @Mock
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private CarParts carParts;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(carController).build();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Car Controller Test")
    public void carControllerTest() {

        try {
            CarCustomRequest carCustomRequest = buildRequest();
            ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/custom/endpoint")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(carCustomRequest)));
            MvcResult mvcResult = resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
            assertTrue(mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus() == 200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Error testing /custom/endpoint");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to `@Autowire` you need to load component classes that create the corresponding bean. To make tests faster you could define custom application context and load required beans only inter of using `@SpringBootTest` without params.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
class ObjectMapperTest {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    void checkObjectMapper() {
        assertNotNull(mapper);
    }
}
```

I would not use `@Mock` in this case because it will be required to create stubs for required methods.

As an alternative, you could simply create a new instance of the `ObjectMapper` in test.

```
class ObjectMapperTest {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    void checkObjectMapper() {
        assertNotNull(mapper);
    }
}
```

You could also register additional modules if required

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it work without using the @SpringBootTest annotation, I just want the jackson object mapper

Comment: As I mentioned, you could simply create a new instance of the `ObjectMapper` in test.

Comment: Could you show in your answer how to do that because it is always null bro, you can not say new ObjectMapper, also the factory from where you can get the object is also null, so at the end I had to use annotation @WebMvcTest and a ton of MockedBeans and also the autowired to my ObjectMapper, but I can not believe there is no way to simply instantiate it

Comment: updated the answer with more examples